# How does one prove that two norms are equal if and only if their closed 1-balls are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space and let $||\bullet||_1$ and $||\bullet||_2$ be two [norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) on $X$. I wish to prove that $||x||_1=||x||_2$ for all $x\in X$
if and only if $\{ x\in X \text{ such that }||x||_1\leq1\}=\{ x\in X \text{ such that }||x||_2\leq1\}$.

Of course, the forward implication of this is very trivial. The converse however I am finding rather tricky. Can anybody prove this or perhaps give a useful hint?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: Let $x\not =0$. If you put $y=x/|x\|_1$, you get $\|y\|_1=1$, hence $\|y\|_2\leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\|x\|_1 \le 1 \implies \|x\|_2 \le 1.$

For any $x \not= 0$ you can let $y = x /\|x\|_1$ so that $\|y\|_1 = 1$ and thus $\|y\|_2 \le 1$. In other words, $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$.

Likewise, if $\|x\|_2 \le 1 \implies \|x\|_1 \le 1$, then $\|x\|_1 \le \|x\|_2$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is generally true, but it's true for normed vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ at least.

To see this you have only have to normalize the vector. Let $\alpha_1=|x|_1$ then $|x/\alpha|_1 = 1$ so $x/\alpha$ is in $B_1$ and therefore in $B_2$ so $|x/\alpha_1|_2\le1$. Which means that $|x|_2\le |x|_1$ and the other way around works too.